# Tkinter - no-egde-resizable window, but working fullscreen button

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

i want to have non-edge-resizable window in python, but working fullscreen button.

I AM NOT ASKING FOR `root.resizable(False, False)`.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want and what do you dont want..?

Comment: I want working maximize(fullscreen) button and I dont want resizable edges.

Comment: Nothing by default

Comment: What?***********

Comment: There is no default way to do this, you will have to play around with bindings